# Python builtin max function throwing 'dict' object has no attribute 'max' for list type object

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, built-in

I have below line of code as a part of my pyspark pipeline (that hard coded list is being fetched from config file) and I am running my pipeline in EMR. Below is the EMR Bootstrap image. The builtin function is treating list of int as dict and throwing below error. Any idea on why I am seeing this weird behavior?

```
    max_n_days = __builtins__.max([10, 20])
```

EMR Bootstrap:

```
 #!/bin/bash

sudo easy_install pip
sudo yum install -y tkinter tk-devel
sudo yum install -y python3-pip
sudo pip install boto3
sudo pip install configparser
sudo pip install paramiko
sudo pip install nltk
sudo pip install scipy
sudo pip install scikit-learn
sudo pip install pandas==0.24.2
sudo pip install -U keras
sudo pip install pyddq
sudo pip install torch
sudo pip install numpy 
sudo pip install future
sudo pip install keras==2.2.4
sudo pip install PyArrow==0.15.1
sudo pip install --upgrade awscli
```

Error:

```
max_n_days = __builtins__.max([10, 20])  # use buildins reference
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'max'
None
```

Note: I am using '**builtins**.max()' as 'max' is colliding with sql max function. I am using python 2.7 on emr and have also tried 'import builtins' but I got builtins not found. Based on suggestions in other stack overflow post I have installed ' future' on my cluster but no luck and still got builtins not found.

Comment: The error message comes from `__builtins__.max`, not `max([10, 20])`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#builtins-and-restricted-execution

Comment: You found a way to call the `max()` function that is as strange as it is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have used 'builtins__.max' because 'max' function is colliding with sql max function.

Comment: Did you try `__builtins__["max"]([10,20])`?  Just kidding.  This is not The Way.

Comment: As the aforelinked documentation says: *don't touch `__builtins__`.* Use `import builtins` instead.

Comment: On Python 2.x, it’s [`import __builtin__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#builtins-and-restricted-execution) (emphasis mine):

> By default, when in the `__main__` module, `__builtins__` is the built-in module `builtins`; *when in any other module, `__builtins__` is an alias for the dictionary of the `builtins` module itself*.

The above explains why you're seeing `__builtins__` as a dictionary inside your Pyspark job.

Also from the same docs:

> **CPython implementation detail**: Users should not touch `__builtins__`; it is strictly an implementation detail. Users wanting to override values in the `builtins` namespace should import the `builtins` module and modify its attributes appropriately.

Solution: use `import builtins` followed by `builtins.max()`.

Comment: Do add this too: https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html

Answer (score 4):

**DO NOT DO** `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`. This overrides `sum`, `max`, `min`, `round`, etc. builtin functions of Python, and you will regret it.

Always use `import pyspark.sql.functions as F` (or your favourite alias), and call Spark functions using `F.sum`, `F.max`, `F.min`, etc.